# Is there any way we can export the Antd table data into an excel sheet on button click with reactjs

Tags: reactjs, antd

I am new to reactjs. I got a scenario in which the Antd table data need to be exported to an excel sheet on a button click. Is there any default options available with Antd? or we need to do some custom development for same. Any pointers will be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Can you provide us some code about how do you get information to tables?. But if my memory is fine, Antd tables receives an array type to display information. You can use the library  [React-json-excel](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-json-excel) to use the same information source and convert it to CSV which is supported by excel.

Answer (score 4):

You can use library react-csv to convert the table data into an .csv file. You can refer to the docs for the onClick props.

```
import { CSVLink } from "react-csv";
            
    <CSVLink
        data={data}
        onClick={() => {
        console.log("clicked") 
        }}
    >
    Download me
    </CSVLink>
        
    <Table
       columns={columns}
       dataSource={data}
    />
```

Answer (score -1):

It seems like react-csv not work properly on macOS (on Safari). You can use:

`npm i antd-table-saveas-excel`
This lib will work like charm with antd.

```
import { Excel } from "antd-table-saveas-excel";

<Table
   columns={columnsTable}
   dataSource={dataTable}
/>

//Printing function
const handlePrint = () => {
const excel = new Excel();
excel
  .addSheet("sheet 1")
  .addColumns(columnsTable)
  .addDataSource(dataTable, {
    str2Percent: true
  })
  .saveAs("Excel.xlsx");
};
```

Here is the link codeSandbox for demonstration:
https://codesandbox.io/embed/antd-table-excel-teedu?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark